# AngularJS module .run order and e2e mocks

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-module

I am working on some E2E tests for AngularJS.

I have implemented a $httpBackend ngMockE2E.

This works well, however in some instances HTTP requests are being made before my mocks have been completely set up.

The Mock is set up as:

```
  angular.module('Mock', ['ngMockE2E']).

    run(function($httpBackend) {

      $httpBackend.whenPOST('/path1').respond({ exampleresponse: 'valid' });
      $httpBackend.whenPOST('/path2').respond({ exampleresponse: 'valid' });
```

And it is used as below:

```
angular.module('Application', ['FirstDependency', 'Mock', 'ThirdDependency']);
```

However FirstDependency and ThirdDependency can make HTTP requests which sometimes happen before the Mock .run() block has been executed. This results in request errors.

Am I setting up my mocks correctly? What is the best way to ensure my mocks are loaded in the right order?

Answer (score 0):

This is what the doc says:

```
Dependencies: 

Modules can list other modules as their dependencies.
Depending on a module implies that required module needs to be loaded
before the requiring module is loaded. In other words the
configuration blocks of the required modules execute before the
configuration blocks of the requiring module. The same is true for the
run blocks. Each module can only be loaded once, even if multiple
other modules require it.
```

However what it doesn't say is that it will **first** execute the config blocks for all modules (*dependencies first*) and **then** it will execute all the other blocks in a row for each module in turn. For an illustration of this take a look at this jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/9FJnZ/2/